# Jquery script not working when uploaded

Tags: jquery, html

This is probably a bit of a noob question but seeing as I am a noob when it comes to JQuery I will need some help. Basically, my homebrewed image gallery script works fine when I test it locally, but one uploaded the script jsut doesn't work. I have no clue as to why?

You can see the website [here](http://designbykai.com/test/index.html)

Here is the [JQuery](http://designbykai.com/test/imagegallery.js)

THE BASIC HTML:

```
<div id="imagenav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>

<div id="imagecontainer">
    <div>
        <a class="prev" href="">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="">next</a>
        <a class="index" href="">X</a><br>
        <img src="images/1.jpg"><br>
        <p>Description: Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="prev" href="">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="">next</a>
        <a class="index" href="">X</a><br>
        <img src="images/2.jpg"><br>
        <p>Description: Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="prev" href="">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="">next</a>
        <a class="index" href="">X</a><br>
        <img src="images/3.jpg"><br>
        <p>Description: Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE BASIC JQUERY SCRIPT:

```
 var imagenav= $('#imagenav li a');
 var imagecontainer= $('#imagecontainer');
 var images= $('#imagecontainer div');
 var shader= $('#shader');

 imagenav.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageno = imagenav.index(this);
    imagecontainer.fadeIn(300, function(){
            shader.fadeIn(300);
            images.hide(0);
            images.eq(imageno).fadeIn(300);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your included jQuery script throws an error:

```
<script src="jquery.js">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /test/jquery.js
    on this server.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
    error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 Server at designbykai.com Port 80</address>
    </body></html> 
</script>
```

**Try this instead:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in your code (imagegallery.js) you could preserve the *dollar* reference to jQuery:

```
(function($){

   //code here  

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh!? I wonder why that has happened? Well that did it! thanks man!

Comment: @bestfriendsforever you're welcome. Good job, now it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery did not load on your page:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

due to:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

On file `http://designbykai.com/test/jquery.js`. Just give 755 permissions to such file [via SSH or FTP], or even better link to jQuery via a CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You page will load faster by the way.

Comment: "or even better link to jQuery via a CDN"? [This document](http://zoompf.com/2010/01/should-you-use-javascript-library-cdns) begs to differ. I feel that changing the permissions is the "better" way to go.

Comment: The only reason we bother with jQuery on a CDN is to show our mobile users love. Some of them have to pay for data, no reason to rape them in the jQuery department.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for firefox you can tell right away that your js is not being downloaded.
It returns "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://designbykai.com/test/jquery.js"

You may want to check that your file exists and its permissions

Comment: I see! i guess i change the permissions under sharing and permissions in that files' info? Or is it more involved?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your script you have the following two lines:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="imagegallery.js"></script>
```

1. Try putting them at the top of the script
2. Ensure that js files are indeed within the http://designbykai.com/test/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Right click at jquery.js file > properties > make sure other get permission to 'read only' for this file. I'am using linux but I think it's just the same for windows too. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score -1):

Line 140...

```
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

is wrong.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

and be sure the file exists and is accessible at the path you are referencing.

Comment: `type` attribute is optional in HTML5.

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional in HTML 5 (which the Doctype of the page in question matches), and its absence wouldn't cause the described problem even if it were mandatory (since browsers don't care).

Comment: Your answer is wrong. As you can clearly see he uses: `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML5 standard) so `<script>` is an perfectly fine.